# HttpListenerReponse and PHP POST requests

Tags: c#, php, httplistener

Here is how the packets look

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Date: Thu, 18 Oct 2012 13:52:49 GMT
Server: LiteSpeed
Connection: close
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.10
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 35
```

And

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 35
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
Date: Thu, 18 Oct 2012 14:17:13 GMT
Connection: close
```

The GZIP output for both is the same yet the top one which is generated with PHP works and the bottom one which is HttpListenerResponse generated doesn't with a POST request, even though you can view both in a browser. I also do not call cross domain/port.

How do I make the second request work?

Comment: How can you make the second one work obviously? HttpListenerResponse doesn't seem to work with POST.

Comment: How are you performing the POST request? When you say `the second it doesn't work`, could you please define what `it doesn't work` means? Maybe you got an error message or something?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov  `requestArray[id].open(method,url,true);
 requestArray[id].setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");` is the part where I send the request and `if (requestArray[id].readyState==4 && requestArray[id].status==200)
 { 
  return true;
 }
 else
 {
  return false;
 }` is the part that always returns false for my HttpListener regardless of me sending a message or not (even though I can open it in a browser) for a php script everything works and returns true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added some headers removed some headers everything started working! You need to allow access control origin or it will only work on IE.